# Enable windows server 2012 R2 to use Microsoft account connection

Tags: windows-server-2012, microsoft-account

Is there anyway to enable windows server 2012 R2 to use Microsoft account connection like any account on windows 8.1 can.

I understand that this is not exactly the correct way to run a server, but I'm also having to use another account separate from admin as a workstation account for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to enable the use of Microsoft Account Connection on Windows Server 2012/2012 R2.